# flow: Simpler way to annotate `type | typeof undefined`?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I constantly run into the same issue with flow: I annotate something as `?type` and forget that that accepts `null` so when I do something like this:

```
function foo(data: string = '') {}
function bar(data: ?string) { foo(data); }
```

flow yells at me because `foo(null)` doesn't resolve `data` to a `string`, but `foo(undefined)` does.  So is there a simpler way to write this:

```
function bar(data: string|typeof undefined) {
```

Or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I guess being specific `string|typeof undefined` is a correct way, but if you want to be sure, I'd suggest having a parser line like `data = !!data && data || ''`. This will also protect against cases like `const dummy: any = null; bar(dummy as string);`

Comment: `function bar(data?: string) { foo(data); }` Pay attention to `?` position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof undefined` is `void` in flow.

So what about:

```
function bar(data: string | void | null) {
```

or

```
function bar(data?: string | null) {
```

Comment: `function bar(data?: string) {` is actually exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure Mark! Glad it helped!